# Xcode 6: label won't drag

Tags: ios, xcode, label

Im just picking up ios development, and Im having a stupidly basic problem with xcode...

I open up a new app and open main.storyboard, and drag in a label to the center of the panel:[image]

It just sticks to the right side, and no matter how many times I click on the darned thing, it won't move! I closed the project and started a new one, and that one worked just fine, but the problem keeps appearing just about every other time I open a new project. **why does this keep happening?**

Answer (score 0):

That is a strange problem. You say that if you close the project and start it again, it fixes itself but keeps reappearing.

Few suggestions, try clearing up some ram by closing other, unused apps.

If that does not work, I would say delete Xcode, restart your mac, and start over. Maybe something went wrong during the install.

Answer (score 0):

Storyboards are scrollable and when you scrolled out your views, you cannot make any changes to the views. Try scrolling into the storyboard and then retry moving the label.

Answer (score 0):

It's AutoLayout, which is the highly recommended default for laying out components now.  You need to create constraints to 
position it, using the icons below the layout area.

Some components I've found I need to manipulate via the size inspector, before constraints are applied.

You will need to read up on Auto Layout sooner or later. It may seem like a hassle or drag at first, and a lot of people are cursing when they have to switch to the paradigm, but when you start to master it, it is very powerful. And it really *is* a sensible way to handle the layout across all the new screen sizes and orientations. It developed out of a need to manage that complexity to keep apps looking good.

**Icons in IB where you set constraints for selected views**:

### [image]

Apple has good documentation for how to use Auto Layout as do many bloggers and sites.  You will have to put some hours into getting used to it, but in a day or two you should start seeing good results.

(and don't blame me, I'm just the messenger)